# Getting keys with max value from dictionary with more than one keys with same value

Tags: python, dictionary

How to get keys with maximum values when there are more than one keys with same value.
Example: d = 'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 99, 'e': 4, 'f': 99}, I need to return 'b','f'

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'c': 4, 'b': 99, 'e': 4, 'f': 99}
>>> maxval = max(d.values())
>>> [k for k in d if d[k]==maxval]
['b', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

Damn :P Got beaten by a minute. Cheers m8.

```
maxValue = max(d.values())
print [key for key in d.keys() if d[key]==maxValue]
```